# Issue with red5 installation on linux

Tags: linux, ssh, red5

i am trying to install red5 media server on the linux centOS server. But i am getting an error as:

`/etc/init.d/red5: line 22: if: command not found`

I am using red5 package: 1.0.10 Milestone 7

Please help me to sort out this error.

Comment: ? Which package did you use ? https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/releases .... Please edit your question to include `red5-server-[version]`

Comment: I am using `1.0.10 Milestone 7` package. I edited my question.

Comment: The package name is `red5-server-1.0.10-M7.tar.gz`. Please confirm. Which command resulted in `/etc/init.d/red5: line 22: if: command not found`? .... I.e. an error output without the command is rather useless.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: I'd suggest reviewing this https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/wiki/Installation-on-Linux and also the init.d referenced may not have come from the tarball, so it makes answering this more difficult.